# How do I get a permanent long term authentication token for google apps application?

Tags: php, google-apps, google-authentication

Hi guys I'm working on my google apps application - currently I've build the authentication upon the example available at google namely this [url](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html)

The problem is that the session seems to time out and that everytime I am logged into my google apps account and go to my application I need to authenticate again and go through the screen where google asks me if I should allow the application to access the services like GMAIL, Docs etc listed in the manifest xml file. I don't think I'm doing it right as other applications allow instant access.

Any ideas

Comment: I currently have the same problem, did you ever fix this and then how? My question is located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894660/google-oauth-imap-asking-for-permission-everytime

Answer (score 1):

you should store and reuse the oauth access & secret key. this should avoid the re-authentication with google (or other oauth based services) - unless your access key has been revoked of course.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm authenticating using authsub here.